# unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'

Tags: bash

I try to run this [script](https://code.google.com/p/bashsimplecurses/) to create simple, beautiful windows with bushcurses but there is an error

```
~/bashcurses$ ./myfirstwindow1.sh 
./myfirstwindow1.sh: line 32: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
./myfirstwindow1.sh: line 39: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I have tried to add or delete `'"` but cannot find proper solution.  Can you please help me to identify the cause of the error?

script:

```
#!/bin/bash

. `dirname $0`/simple_curses.sh

main (){
    window "`hostname`" "red"
    append "`date`"
    addsep
    append_tabbed "Up since|`uptime | cut -f1 -d"," | sed 's/^ *//' | cut -f3- -d" "`" 2 "|"
    append_tabbed "Users:`uptime | cut -f2 -d"," | sed 's/^ *//'| cut -f1 -d" "`" 2
    append_tabbed "`awk '{print "Load average:" $1 " " $2 " " $3}' < /proc/loadavg`" 2
    endwin 

    window "Memory usage" "red"
    append_tabbed `cat /proc/meminfo | awk '/MemTotal/ {print "Total:" $2/1024}'` 2
    append_tabbed `cat /proc/meminfo | awk '/MemFree/ {print "Used:" $2/1024}'` 2
    endwin

    window "Processus taking memory and CPU" "green"
    for i in `seq 2 6`; do
        append_tabbed "`ps ax -o pid,rss,pcpu,ucmd --sort=-cpu,-rss | sed -n "$i,$i p" | awk '{printf "%s: %smo:  %s%%" , $4, $2/1024, $3 }'`" 3
    done
    endwin

    window "Last kernel messages" "blue"
    dmesg | tail -n 10 > /tmp/deskbar.dmesg
    while read line; do
        append_tabbed "$line" 1 "~"
    done < /tmp/deskbar.dmesg
    rm -f /tmp/deskbar.dmesg
    endwin

    window "Inet interfaces" "grey"
    ERROR >> _ifaces=$(for inet in `ifconfig | cut -f1 -d " " | sed -n "/./ p"`; do ifconfig $inet | awk 'BEGIN{printf "%s", "'"$inet"'"} /adr:/ {printf ":%s\n", $2}'|sed 's/adr://'; done)
    for ifac in $_ifaces; do
        append_tabbed  "$ifac" 2
    done
    endwin
}
main_loop 1
```

Comment: what operating system are you using? I've just tested on a Mac OSX 10.9 and the script doesn't throw any errors (although I don't see any beautiful windows, but that might be a different story)

Comment: Backticks don't nest quotes well, use `$(...)` everywhere.

Comment: @Kevin how should I convert: append_tabbed "Up since|`uptime | cut -f1 -d"," | sed 's/^ *//' | cut -f3- -d" "`" 2 "|"

Comment: The same as any other pair: `append_tabbed "Up since|$(uptime | cut ...))" 2 "|"`

Comment: And you should consider using temporary variables.

Comment: @Kevin it is OK now, you can put it as an answer, thank you